# changing button order in js

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a series of buttons of fixed height and width, those need to be draggable and droppable anywhere inside the parent div.

As per client request, I cannot use any external libraries, meh... I could have done this with jQuery in seconds but, I guess this is one of its drawbacks: you don't get to learn more basic stuff...

How would I go about doing it? A problem with this is that those buttons are inside a div that is also draggable so I need to be careful about positioning, I can only probably use relative.

Any ideas how I can go about doing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sneak the jQuery UI library in? :)

Comment: I do not think that this one is getting a lot of feedback

Comment: What's the reasoning behind your client disallowing external libraries? Stuff like jQuery is pretty much a standard in web development now.

Comment: @JamWaffles, I know. They're just dumb.

Comment: Tell your client: "There is a library that achieves exactly this. It is far better written than anything I can produce immediately. Why don't you want it?". If they still respond: "We're dumb", then you're screwed. How would you go about this? Write your own library that does exactly the same thing. It will take you ages, and it probably won't be as good. But if you come up with any specific problems or queries while doing it, StackOverflow can help with those.

Comment: @Barney: this is the specific problem I am encoutering. this is all part of a greater thing I am facing. I am not asking for someone to do it for me, I am asking about "how I can go about doing in", maybe with speudocode or some concepts?

Comment: Well, I suppose you could fork jQuery and jQuery UI, put it all in one file, strip out the bits you're not going to use and write your custom functionality into the same file. _Technically_, it's your own library. If your client is dumb enough to not want external libs, are they dumb enough to not see a custom jQuery copy when presented with one?

Answer (score 0):

[Peter-Paul Koch](http://www.quirksmode.org/about/) wrote an [excellent how-to on drag and drop](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/dragdrop.html). I only remembered this 3/4 of the way through writing my own, so I [wrapped that up in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/HtubL/).

```
function makeDraggable(draggable, container){
    // In case you don't want to have a container
    var container = container || window;
    // So we know what to do on mouseup:
    // At this point we're not sure the user wants to drag
    var dragging  = false;

        // The movement listener and position modifier
        function dragHandler(moveEvent){
            moveEvent.preventDefault();

            dragging        = true;

            // Ascertain where the mouse is
            var coordinates = [
                    moveEvent.clientX,
                    moveEvent.clientY
            ];

            // Style properties we need to apply to the element 
            var styleValues = {
                    position : 'absolute',
                    left     : coordinates[0] + 'px',
                    top      : coordinates[1] + 'px'
            };

            // Apply said styles
            for(property in styleValues){
                    if(styleValues.hasOwnProperty(property)){
                            draggable.style[property] = styleValues[property];
                    }
            }
    }

    function dropHandler(upEvent){
        // Only interfere if we've had a drag event
        if(dragging === true){
            // We don't want the button click event to fire!
            upEvent.preventDefault();

            // We don't want to listen for drag and drop until this is clicked again
            container.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragHandler, false);
            draggable.removeEventListener('mouseup',   dropHandler, false);

            dragging = false;
        }
    }

    // Where all the fun happens
    draggable.addEventListener('mousedown', function dragListener(downEvent){
        downEvent.preventDefault();

        // The drag event
        container.addEventListener('mousemove', dragHandler, false);

        // The end of drag, if dragging occurred
        draggable.addEventListener('mouseup',   dropHandler, false);
    }, false);
}​
```

Comment: Note that it is possible to drag the buttons outside the box in my example if you do it very slowly. You might want to add an extra function before applying the position styles that extrapolates container dimensions and position and checks whether the coordinates are within that space.